# Does the kanji term Mitsukoshi 三越 have a meaning when the 2 terms are combined?

Tags: meaning, words, kanji

三越 is the name of a department store. Three is the meaning of the first character and I get the meanings of surpass, cross over, move to, exceed, and Vietnam when I research the term. Is there a meaning for the two terms when combined?

Comment: Per wikipedia: “ 商号の「三越」は、三井家の「三井」と創業時の「越後屋」からとったもので、1904年に「合名会社三井呉服店」から「株式会社三越呉服店」へ改称した際からのものである。”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term Mitsukoshi has no direct English translation, the characters individually mean three and to overtake or surpass. This information was obtained from the Official Gazette of the United States Patent and Trademark Office: Trademarks

> https://books.google.com/books?id=rAvRAAAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA271&lpg=RA1-PA271&dq=mitsukoshi+japanese+meaning&source=bl&ots=VKIquSPko-&sig=ACfU3U17u56m-eMoLBme5SiY3HDen7N_og&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUk-bXyZTlAhXxYN8KHVTuBHo4ChDoATADegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=mitsukoshi%20japanese%20meaning&f=false